# How to pass select/create query as parameter in snowflake stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to pass a parameter to a stored procedure which is basically 'select/create statement'.

I had used `:param` and `INDENTIFIER(:param)` but it is not working.

> Error : invalid identifier and binding error

Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_PROC(query varchar)       
returns varchar
LANGUAGE SQL
as 
$$ 
begin

if(length(query)>=1 and IS_NOTNULL(query) )then
   execute immediate (:query);
--execute immediate IDENTIFIER(:query);
 end if;

end; 
$$;

call TEST_PROC('CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TBL1 AS SELECT * FROM TBL2')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the  "if" line to the following then it should work:

```
if(length(:query)>=1 and :query IS NOT NULL ) then
```

The full code that I ran (which includes return statements to track what the SP is doing) is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_PROC(query varchar)       
returns varchar
LANGUAGE SQL
as 
$$ 
begin

if(length(:query)>=1 and :query IS NOT NULL ) then
   execute immediate (:query);
--execute immediate IDENTIFIER(:query);
else
    RETURN 'No input provided';
 end if;

return 'Query executed: ' || :query;
end; 
$$
;
```

Comment: Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 4 at position 0 : SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 64 unexpected '<EOF>'.

It seems this code has some issue : 
`execute immediate (:query);`